# Qual è il significato di "prata" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> L’ombra proprio non era ancor scesa: campanacci di pecore e capre si sentivano a tratti qua e là un po’ prima della **prata** dei pascoli.

Non so cos'è una "prata". Ho cercato questo termine in parecchi dizionari, ma non l'ho trovato. Sapreste spiegarmene il significato?

Comment: L'unica cosa che mi viene in mente è che sia un sinonimo di _prato_ o _prateria_ ovvero una distesa di erba...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arcaico per "prato".

Per l'uso al singolare, si veda la [Grammatica Storica Della Lingua Italiana e Dei Suoi Dialetti (Vol.2, pag. 60)](https://ia902309.us.archive.org/8/items/GrammaticaStoricaDellaLinguaItaliana2/Grammatica%20storica%20della%20lingua%20italiana%202_text.pdf) di Gerhard Rohlfs da cui cito testualmente:

> Una lunga serie di neutri si continua nel neolatino nell'originaria forma plurale, non raramente accanto all'antica forma singolare.[...omissis...]
>   Accanto a *il prato* si trova *la prata* (Silvio d'Arzo).

Per chi ha interesse segnalo

- il volume **Silvio D'Arzo, lo scrittore e la sua ombra**, *Atti delle giornate di studio, Reggio Emilia, 29-30 ottobre 1982* in cui si trova

  > «"Prata" al femminile è cinquecentesco, registrato dalla Crusca e dal Tommaseo.
- **Lucia Giroletti**, *Silvio D'Arzo (1920-1952): La "Religione" Della Scrittura*
- **Elisa Vignali**, *Silvio D'Arzo scrittore fra la provincia e il mondo*
- bibliografia su [Silvio D'Arzo](http://www.boll900.it/2002-i/BiblioDarzo.html#iii)

Answer (score 1):

In questa [Archeologia e storia di un castello apuano](https://books.google.it/books?id=TB-3CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA236&lpg=PA236&dq=prata%20dei%20pascoli&source=bl&ots=6odB-439M4&sig=g3H2Xh3xEx5pR_2VLbLMQuYvENg&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJreiapI7YAhVBYlAKHSFiCs4Q6AEwDnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=prata%20dei%20pascoli&f=false)  trovi che il termine prata era il toponimo prato utilizzato al neutro plurale latino.

Secondo il libro [Le Padule di Fucecchio: una lunga storia di un ambiente naturale](https://books.google.it/books?id=XDnTQjSV7vYC&pg=PA42&lpg=PA42&dq=prata%20di%20pascoli&source=bl&ots=y-H0f6LshQ&sig=jMtuGORDl7pdkX-wjneAzFzw9DA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidwOegv47YAhUJ1xQKHXiYBaQQ6AEwB3oECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=prata%20di%20pascoli&f=false) per prata di pascoli si intendeva

> Subito dopo la zona dei coltivi si estendeva una fascia lasciata a
>   prato, attestata da luoghi detti Prata, alla Prata, Pratali. Come si
>   evince dallo stesso vocabolo, si trattava di pascoli ormai in larga
>   misura assegnati in godimento a privati, ma dove esistevano anche aree
>   di proprietà comunale.

Comment: Ho visto nel Treccani che "prata" può essere il plurale di "prato". Nel testo però la parola è al singolare.

Comment: @Charo: Forse era successo qualcosa di simile a “frutta”, che in origine era un plurale latineggiante di “frutto” (accanto a “frutti”): “le frutta” > “la frutta”. E cf. anche l'etimo di “opera”.

Comment: Di "prata" come plurale è relativamente facile trovare esempi. Il singolare "prata" sembra invece di uso più ristretto: il GDLI, oltre che "antico", lo qualifica come di uso "letterario".

Answer (score 1):

Per aggiungere una fonte in più alla risposta di @alexjo, il [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000033.jpg) dà "prata" come una variante antica e letteraria di "prato" e cita un esempio di uso di Guido Cavalcanti:

> **Prato** [...]   ant. e letter.  anche sf. *prade*, *prata*, *prate*, *pràtora* [...]. 
>     [...]  *G. Cavalcanti*, XXXV-II-491:  Fresca  rosa  novella,  /
> piacente  primavera,  /  per  prata  e  per  rivera  /  gaiamente cantando,  /  vostro  fin  presio  mando  a  la  verdura. [...].

E [più avanti](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI14/00000034.jpg), col significato di "piana erbosa, prateria", appare anche un esempio dalle *Novelle* di [Giovanni Sercambi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/giovanni-sercambi):

> – Piana erbosa; prateria. 
>     *Sercambi*, 1-124:  Li  Fiorentini,  vedendo  quella  brigata, presero  la  via  della  prata  et  atraversonno  alla  strada  di Sanpiero  a  Grado  et  andonno  a  Livorna  e  ultimamente l’ebbero. [...].

Comment: Che problema ha questa risposta?

Comment: Forse il problema è che "prata" nell'esempio del Cavalcante è plurale? A me è sembrato che fosse singolare, nello stesso modo che ["rivera"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riviera/), forma anche di uso antico e poetico, è singolare. Ma, in effetti, potrebbe essere plurale.